# figure within paragraph, not moving figure to the next page

Tags: floats

I am trying to place a figure within a paragraph. I would like LaTeX to break the paragraph as if it was end of the page, but just before the figure. I have tried using package float with `\begin{figure}[H]` but it didn't work, it moved the figure to the next page. Any ideas on how to do this?

If I manually move the text below, the initial part of the paragraph is not justified anymore.

Comment: Floats will be placed according to the available space. Apparently the space in this paragraph isn't sufficient to accommodate the float in the position you want it to appear. You could try to use the `wrapfig` package that places a float next to text.

Comment: One approach is avoiding a float environment, with some drawbacks. And you can reduce size or width of the drawing. // A suggestion: perceive and welcome this element as one of Latex‘ nice features to „create beautiful documents“. And no, Word and similar don‘t do that. Re-learn print.

Comment: If you add a [b] float before the last paragraph, it will split the paragraph at the bottom of the page (if it fits and if there are no other floats in the queue).